# How does System V amd64 handle very long return values?

Tags: assembly, posix, return-value, x86-64, abi

I'm briefly studying the System V ABI for amd64 / x86-64 architecture, and am curious how it handles return values over 128 bits, where `rax` and `rdx` aren't enough.

I wrote the following C code on Ubuntu 18.04 64-bit (more generally, any amd64 POSIX-compliant system):

```
struct big {
    long long a, b, c, d;
};

struct big bigfunc(void) {
    struct big r = {12, 34, 56, 78};
    return r;
}
```

Compiled it as `gcc -S -masm=intel t.c`, and inspected `t.s`:

```
        .file   "t.c"
        .intel_syntax noprefix
        .text
        .globl  bigfunc
        .type   bigfunc, @function
bigfunc:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        mov     QWORD PTR -40[rsp], rdi
        mov     QWORD PTR -32[rsp], 12
        mov     QWORD PTR -24[rsp], 34
        mov     QWORD PTR -16[rsp], 56
        mov     QWORD PTR -8[rsp], 78
        mov     rcx, QWORD PTR -40[rsp]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR -32[rsp]
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR -24[rsp]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rcx], rax
        mov     QWORD PTR 8[rcx], rdx
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR -16[rsp]
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR -8[rsp]
        mov     QWORD PTR 16[rcx], rax
        mov     QWORD PTR 24[rcx], rdx
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR -40[rsp]
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
        .size   bigfunc, .-bigfunc
        .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 7.3.0"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

No surprise that the struct definition doesn't compile into any instructions, so the output only contains function `bigfunc`. The output assembly looks pretty straightforward, allocating memory from stack for `struct big r` and assign initial values, and returning it.

If I am understanding correctly, before `ret` is executed, register `rax` contains the value of `rdi` at the beginning of the function call (from `QWORD PTR -40[rbp]`). According to SysV, `rdi` is the first argument supplied to the function, which is impossible because the function accepts no arguments. So I have a few questions here:

1. What is `rdi` when the function `bigfunc` takes no arguments?
2. What is `rax` (as the register that contains return value), when `rdx` is not touched in this function?
3. How does the function return this 256-bit C structure?

Comment: This code would be much easier to understand if you enabled optimisations.  TL;DR:  as specified in the [ABI document](https://www.uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf), structures are returned by passing a pointer to the structure as a hidden first argument.

Comment: @fuz Skimmed through the menu but didn't find the keyword "return value". Mind pointing out the section number? Thanks.

Comment: It may not be in the amd64-specific document - this is a general rule that applies to all architectures.

Comment: @iBug See page 22.  It's all part of §3.2.3.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley: what?  it's up to each calling convention/ABI on each architecture to specify how large objects are returned.  e.g. if multiple registers are used before falling back to memory, and if memory whether to pass a hidden pointer (usually as a first arg, but details need to be specified; it could pass in a register that's normally not an arg-passing register) or to leave the value on the stack (kind of the opposite of callee-pops for args), or whatever.

Comment: All the calling conventions I'm familiar with pass a hidden first arg when falling back to memory, but x86-64 SysV and Windows x64 differ in how they return objects from 9 to 16 bytes.  i386 SysV also differs from some 32-bit Windows conventions, e.g. never returning structs in edx:eax, only int64_t.  (So that's a difference between i386 and x86-64 SysV in how they pack return vals into regs or not).  The generic System V ABI definitely leaves it up to each psABI (platform supplement) to define the details of returning large objects; there's no universal convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [ABI](https://www.uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf) (1) ,page 22

> If the type has class MEMORY, then the caller provides space for the return
> value and passes the address of this storage in %rdi as if it were the first
> argument to the function. In effect, this address becomes a “hidden” first ar-
> gument. This storage must not overlap any data visible to the callee through
> other names than this argument.
> On return %rax will  contain  the  address  that  has  been  passed  in  by  the
> caller in %rdi

Page 17, 18 and 19 describes the classifications, I beliveve
the following on page 19 is the clause designating your `struct big` as a MEMORY class.

> (c)  If the size of the aggregate exceeds two eightbytes and the first
> eight- byte isn’t SSE or any other eightbyte isn’t SSEUP, the whole
> argument is passed in memory.

i.e. the caller have to allocate memory for the return value, and pass a pointer to that memory in %rdi (and the called function returns that same address in %rax)

(1) there's newer offical versions of the ABI at https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI , though the links arn't currently working properly.

Comment: The `struct big` in my example is exactly 4 eightbytes, can you address that?

Comment: See the updates. You likely have to read page 17,18 and 19 to view the rules yourself, they are not that straight forward.